# R rgl Package crashes Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

Does anyone use R rgl package (version 0.95.1201) in Rstudio (Version 0.99.489)? Every time I call `library(rgl)`, Rstudio crashes.

**Update**

I updated rgl by installing version 0.95.1367 from source. Rstudio still crashes. But when I run it in R GUI or R in terminal, there is no problem. Recently I updated my XQuartz to 2.7.9_beta1. I am not sure if this could be the reason.

My system is: Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

[image]

Comment: I installed rgl-0.95.1367 from source, but Rstudio still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

You have to set the environment variable:

> LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

In R, the command is:

```
Sys.setenv(LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1)
```

It should work now.

Comment: On OSX El Captain, the problem appears again...any ideas?

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

install latest `RTools` to default folder (C:\rtools##) from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)
check `RTOOLS##_HOME` *envvar* is in your path
install `devtools` package
install `rgl` package from github sources, with a line
`devtools::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")`
the problem should go away

Comment: But OP is on macOS as you can see from the screenshot.