# Rstudio freezes when loading some packages

Tags: r, rstudio

When i was loading some packages like"rgl", "aplpack", whenever there's gonna be a red stop sign on the right top corner of console window.

My Rstudio just freezes, like

[image]

I typed the code like an hour ago, and it is still loading.

But other functions work fine. My Rstudio still can run a lot of functions if the red stop sign doesn't need to appear.

I have reinstalled Rstudio a lot of times, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The Rstudio is installed on Mac OS X El Caption

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027425/r-rgl-package-crashes-rstudio

Comment: and i have updated everything